# PHP array_search() using value from end()

Tags: php

I have a PHP array that I am displaying the last item from using **end()** that looks like this...

```
$people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");
echo end($people);
```

I am now trying to take that last value and use it to search another array using **array_search()** like this...

```
$result = array_search(end($people), array_column($new_array, 'people' ));
```

But this is not working, if I manually put the value in then it works so I am assuming it is an issue with how using **end()** within and array_search

Is there a way to save the **end()** value as a variable that I can then include in my **array_search()** function?

Comment: Store value in variable and then try $value = end($people)

Comment: I have tried to save the result of end() as a variable but it just gives me the array again

Comment: @Pierre your statement about the second call is incorrect: https://3v4l.org/1FgLK

Comment: @jsmitter3, what do you get in the `$result` variable?

Comment: @jsmitter3 what is the outcome of `array_column($new_array, 'people')`? And what is the outcome of `end($people)` just before the `array_search()` line? I suspect the `$people` array does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: So, what happens if you store the result of `array_column` in a variable, store the result of `end` in a variable, and then call `array_search` passing those variables as arguments. If the result still is not okay, at least you can check those intermediate values. By nesting all the call like you do now, you make it really hard for yourself to debug this code. There is no shame in having three lines of code. ;)

Comment: Think I have worked out why I am not getting the results I am expecting, updating original post now!